# compiler sdk version and target sdk version change in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, target

I installed Android Studio 1.4 .By default it has settings for compiler sdk and target sdk as MARSHMALLOW . So if i generated final APK after completion of my project, is it works in previous versions of android with out any error ..??

Comment: post your build.gradle file.

Comment: is this issue resolved ?

Answer (score 0):

**No Absolutely Not**

To work fine you have to mention target sdk like

```
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
```

in Manifest file OR in build.gradle file.

My build.gradle contains

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.everestek.login"
    minSdkVersion 19

    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

Comment: i installed latest studio and changed the target and compiled sdk versions to lollipop from marshmallow after these changes project is not working its showing these erorrs                                                                       Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.

Comment: You keep                                                                     compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2" just change target sdk and try

Answer (score 0):

Your compile SDK version must match the support library's major version.

Since you are using version 23 of the support library, you need to compile against version 23 of the Android SDK.

Alternatively you can continue compiling against version 22 of the Android SDK by switching to the latest support library v22.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.suhasbachewar.demo"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will work perfectly.All you need to do is just change `minSdkVersion` to `16` or any level you want to extend your support.Compile SDK version is for compiling using build tools.There will be no problem with it.You can Provide support to older devices.